# If I'm using a 1d array to represent a square board, how can I take my index and check the squares above, below and to its sides?

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic, modulo

If I have a 4x4 gameboard which I'm representing in my program as a 1d integer array of size 16.

How can I get the indexs of the squares above, below, to the left and to the right any given index?

So, for example:

```
A = { 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 }
```

Which represents this board

```
 0   1   2   3
 4   5   6   7
 8   9  10  11
12  13  14  15
```

Lets say I am currently on index #8 in the board (value = 7).  How can I get the index for 4 (value = 3) , 5 (value = 6), 10 (value = 11) and realize that there is no right square because it is on the right hand edge of the board.

I know I need to use some modulus math but I'm failing to come up with the right way to get the indexes for adjacent squares.

I'm thinking something like...

```
if ((i % 4) + 1 < 3) right = i + 1;
if ((i % 4) - 1 > 0) left = i - 1;
if ((i % 4) + 4 < 15) bottom = i + 4;
if ((i % 4) - 4 > 0 ) top = i - 4;
```

Does this seem like it is the right approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get row,column from your index, use the following:

```
row = index/num_columns;
column = index % num_columns;
```

to get back to the index, use

```
index = row * num_columns + column;
```

One you're in rows and columns, it's easy to get the surrounding positions.

```
above = (row-1, column)
left = (row, column-1)
etc...
```